# Safari not catching exception when trying to access parent window object with Javascript try/catch

Tags: javascript, macos, exception, safari, try-catch

So the code below can be seen working via the fiddle link. Safari is refusing to catch the exception- I am assuming this may be because it is not a 'Javascript' error? Either way, if you run the code in any other browser, you will see the page URL in the console.

The purpose of the function is find the page URL when executed multiple iframes deep on the page. If anyone can confirm why Safari won't catch the error and/or maybe offer a solution, that would be great...Thanks!

```
function logURL() {
    var oFrame = window, 
        exception = false;

    try {
        while (oFrame.parent.document !== oFrame.document) {
            oFrame = oFrame.parent;
        }
    } catch (e) {
        exception = true;
    }

     if(exception) {
         console.log('excepted', oFrame.document.referrer);
     } else {
         console.log('no exception', oFrame.location.href);
     }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HPu9n/82/

Comment: In my computer safari console is showing the url. no exception http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28241940/safari-not-catching-exception-when-prodding-window-object

Comment: Thanks Sandro- This is a problem on Safari running on OSX, are you on OSX as well?

Comment: I can reproduce this in Safari 7.1.3 on OS X.

Comment: I am Safari Version 7.0.3 and OS X Version 10.9.2

Comment: Hmm, ok- thanks, well I'm using Safari 7.1.3 like @AlexanderO'Mara so maybe it is an issue with this version only...Maybe if you update you will see the same error? I am using OSX 10.9.5.

Comment: Also tested on Safari 8.0.2 and 8.0.3 and the same issue occurs.

Comment: Still an issue in Safari 9.1.2. Getting the feeling they aren't going to fix this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While an error is logged to the Safari console, Safari apparently does not thrown a JavaScript exception when accessing a window property across frame origins. Instead, Safari simply returns `undefined` for any property which is not accessible cross-origin.

With this knowledge, we can simply check if `oFrame.parent.document` is set, and if it's not, break off the loop an do what would happen if the browser threw an exception.

### Example ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ggh0a0f4/)):

```
function logURL() {
    var oFrame = window, 
        exception = false;

    try {
        while (oFrame.parent.document !== oFrame.document) {
            //Check if document property is accessible.
            if (oFrame.parent.document) {
                oFrame = oFrame.parent;
            }
            else {
                //If document was not set, break the loop and set exception flag.
                exception = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {
        exception = true;
    }

    if(exception) {
        console.log('excepted', oFrame.document.referrer);
    } else {
        console.log('no exception', oFrame.location.href);
    }
}
logURL();
```

### Logs:

```
excepted http://jsfiddle.net/ggh0a0f4/
```

Comment: Aha! Thankyou Alexander- I am still fairly confused as to why Safari behaves in this way, though I certainly won't lose any sleep over it ;)
Thanks very much for the help, certainly deserves the bounty! 
The solution seems quite simple in hindsight, though as always with these things, it takes the right perspective to figure it out.